# Vite Typescript - const enum are not inlined

Tags: typescript, vite

I'm using a `Vite` build with default settings and `const enum` are not inlined in the final build

Example code:

```
// types.ts
export const enum TestConstEnum {
  Test1,
  Test2,
  Test3,
}
```

```
// test.ts
import { TestConstEnum } from "./types";

export function test() {
  console.log(TestConstEnum.Test1, TestConstEnum.Test2);
}
```

Transpiled to:

```js
var r = /* @__PURE__ */ ((e) => (e[e.Test1 = 0] = "Test1", e[e.Test2 = 1] = "Test2", e[e.Test3 = 2] = "Test3", e))(r || {});
function t() {
  console.log(r.Test1, r.Test2);
}
export {
  t as test
};
```

Expected result:

```js
function t() {
  console.log(0, 1);
}
export {
  t as test
};
```

Here is the default `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "lib"]
}
```

Note that when the `const enum` is not imported (defined in same file) it get transpiled as expected, I also tried `"isolatedModules": false` same result,

Comment: Which version of Vite are you using? If it's not the latest, do you still have the same problem with the latest version?

Comment: Nevermind, it will be [an issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10384#issuecomment-1272840595) as long as esbuild does not do the bundling.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that, a `wontfix` issue ... Guess I'll have to work with the `define` option

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of googling and a wasted half day, it seems that `vite` and most modern bundlers, does not support inlined `const enum` because of the way they operate.

On the bright side, I managed to make it work using the [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) option, it's not the prettiest solution but it get the job done and you don't have to reconfigure your `const enums`.

You can add the `define` option to your `vite.config.ts` as follow:

```js
//vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig, UserConfigExport } from "vite";

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {

    const config: UserConfigExport = {
        //...the default config
    }

    if (command === "build")
        config.define = {
             "TestConstEnum.Test1": 0,
             "TestConstEnum.Test2": 1,
             "TestConstEnum.Test3": 2,
        }
   
    return config;
});
```

Comment: one year later, this helped. My page was completely blank without error, using this solved the issue. thx